Installing a new meter and main panel to home during addition
I have an older home, built nearly 100 years ago, and it's been brutalized by several owners and hack electricians.  To make things even better, it has a total of 70amp service, and currently is probably wired for at least 100amps if not more. And, the panels (yes, plural) for the breakers are in the cellar.  One the breakers hardly move, the other breaker panel is pulled from the old breaker panel and is seriously overloaded (dryer, baseboard heaters, water heater, more).  So, I'm going to try and fix it.
I am adding an addition to the home, and in the process, I plan to move all the power from the outside meter box and take it up to 200amps.  But I really  don't want to move or pull all those circuits from the old house because honestly they aren't all accessible.
The kitchen however IS accessible, so I'm going to move the electric range power, and rewire the kitchen outlets into the new circuit breaker (this means they will be removed from the OLD panels in the cellar).
The dryer will move because we are moving the laundry into the renovation on the main floor, and so the circuit for that will go away.  Just losing those circuits should make it possible to realign all the circuits in the cellar into ONE panel that is properly balanced.
I also am running a circuit (50amp) out to my barn/metal building.
So, with all that in mind, is it possible to do one of the following?

could I buy a meter base with a primary disconnect, but with 3-4 circuits, and run one to the new renovation circuit breaker to power that main panel, run another to the old cellar panel that is cleaned up, and then run the 50amp out to the barn?

same idea, but instead just run the main power to the main panel, run a new line from there to what will become a subpanel in the cellar, and then the 50amp from the meter box?

just run all the power to the new main panel, and run the line to the cellar subpanel, and another to the barn with a 50amp subpanel.


Any thoughts are welcome.


Any of the three should be possible.  New circuits will need to be done on the most recent electric code in your location.  New circuits are any that more work than just replacing receptacles/fixtures, so GFCI/AFCI protection.  Old circuits not changed, might be recommended to have AFCI protection(breakers/receptacles) on them if you do not trust prior work done/insurance requires for fire.  Your local power company will have specs/requirements on what type of meter bases you can use.  Check with them first before running out to big box store and buying the pretty one.

Thanks, yes, part of the reason I'm just rewiring the kitchen into the new main panel instead of chasing it and updating it from the cellar panel is that it isn't close to being in code.  The entire kitchen has two four way boxes, no GFCI/AFCI anywhere.  The wiring for the one 4-way outlet box literally comes off where the sink light is and along the outside wall, and punches in the wall.  No weatherproofing, just wire hanging out in the wind.

Wiring done to code at the time is good.  If never done to code at the time it is a mess that has to be redone.  GFCI near water should be done/recommended, but not must be.  AFCI is recommended for old wiring done in code of the time.

@TrentLamb what make and model are the existing breaker panels?

Also @TrentLamb who's your electric utility?

Utility now is Rocky Mtn Power, years ago it was Utah Power.

Breakers, no idea older than I am

Pictures of the existing panels would help.  With any door open and closed (two different pictures).  Writing or text should be legible (take a closeup if necessary).  Some panels should be replaced simply because they're bad panels.  It's possible that the advice you need is to replace the existing panel.  Or not.  Thus the request for the make/model.  If you don't know, pictures may help people here figure it out.

I added pictures, but the moderator blocked the post

you're supposed to add them by editing your question above, but it looks like you figured that out.

Your overarching question seems to be "where do I begin - how do I start chipping away at this monstrous task?" You'll need to come up with a written plan that your city building official and Rocky Mountain Power are happy with.

The first step in an overhaul of this magnitude really should be a "load calculation." This will consider general lighting loads plus specific loads including water heating, air conditioning, laundry, cooking, other machinery/tools, and vehicle charging, and will indicate the minimum ampacity of your service. That, in turn, dictates the minimum size of main panel. The calculation may turn up a result well below 200 amps and you're free to round up to that level. It's important to do the calculation to be sure you don't require anything larger.
You can have as many or as few subpanels as you wish. It makes sense to install new subpanels in the places where your existing subpanels are to minimize the number of circuit extensions required. You'll use the same load calculation process for subpanels and their respective feeders as for the main panel.
Consider whether you want to lay groundwork for PV solar or backup generator. Some meter-main panels have special provisions to make these additions easy ("Solar ready" panels, panels with an available interlock kit for manual generator transfer, etc). Some panels have feed-through lugs which can be used to carry power to an indoor subpanel; this might or might not be beneficial in your scenario. Somehow you'll have to pick among the brands and models available to you a meter-main panel that is acceptable to RMP and has enough slots and other features to suit your need. Review the RMP Electric Service Requirements Manual for all the details -- but in a nutshell, you'll need a panel with a ring-type meter socket, EUSERC rated, and 3" conduit if fed undeground.
Make a decision as to where you want the new meter-main service panel to be located (on the existing building or on the addition). Contact RMP, probably by picking "new construction" on their phone menu, and request to meet with a field representative about your service upgrade. They'll schedule a person to come to your site. The customer is responsible to provide the meter-main panel and the conduit when fed underground; RMP provides the conductors. You'll discuss with the field rep the location where you want the new service panel to go, where they want the buried conduit to run or details of the aerial drop, etc. They'll confirm that their existing equipment has available capacity to serve your upgrade.
Note: for me the biggest stress in a main panel replacement is the race against time to have the service disconnected, tear down the old equipment, install the new, get it inspected, and call RMP for the re-connect all in 4-6 hours so that I don't have power out overnight. If you put your new panel beside the old one (or in an entirely new place) then you can set it up as a subpanel off the existing main, move circuits and feeders to the new panel at your leisure, and really minimize the work that has to wait until disconnect day.
Take your plans with calculations to the city and apply for an electrical building permit.
Do the work.
Disconnect day. Note: RMP will disconnect on request. However, they won't re-connect until they've received notice of successful inspection from the city. You schedule the service disconnect with RMP a few days in advance. They'll remove your meter and de-energize the service conductors. If your new panel was fully prepared and inspected in advance then they'll proceed to hook that up immediately. Otherwise, you get to work finishing whatever needs to be done for the new panel, get it inspected, and then call RMP to request the re-connect.

